# Cannot pass variable to js file

Tags: javascript

I cannot pass variable to js file, from my `common.module`

```
  $max_length = 10; //variable_get('title_max_length');
      drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'myTHEME'). '/js/script.js');
      drupal_add_js(array('common' => array('max' => $max_length)), array('type' => 'setting'));
```

Javascript works fine, but i need to get `**$max_length**` variable from module. At the moment its not working.
here is js file:

```
(function($, Drupal) {
/*Character limit for news node*/

    Drupal.behaviors.common = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
            var length = $('#edit-title').val().length;
           /* ####################################### */
           /* Does not work */
            var char_limit = Drupal.settings.common.max; 
           /* ####################################### */
            if (length >= char_limit) {
                $('div.form-item-title label span.form-required').text("characters left limit exceeded for displaying on home page");
            } else {
                $('div.form-item-title label span.form-required').text(char_limit-length-1 + " characters left");
            }

            $('#edit-title:not(.edit-title-processed)', context).keyup(function () {

                $(this).addClass('edit-title-processed');
                var new_length = $('#edit-title').val().length;

                if (new_length >= char_limit) {
                    var chars = char_limit-new_length;
                    $('#edit-title').css('color','red');
                    //$('div.form-item-title label span.form-required').text("characters left limit exceeded for displaying on home page");
                    $('div.form-item-title label span.form-required').text("" + chars-1 + " characters");


                } else {
                    var chars = char_limit-new_length;
                    $('div.form-item-title label span.form-required').text(chars-1 + " characters left");
                    $('#edit-title').css('color', 'black');

                }
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Comment: Did you clear your page cache and browser cache ? Try printing Drupal.settings.common.max in firebug or console of chrome browser ...

Comment: yesi cleared cache

Comment: Firebug shows me just a = `var char_limitDrupal.settings.common.max_length;` and script did not working and also `Drupal.settings.common is undefined`

Comment: Try printing Drupal.settings.common.max in firebug.. Let us know what do you see ..

Comment: I am closing the question as too localized, as [the OP said](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48372/cannot-pass-variable-to-js-file#comment49990_48376), "it was a wrong code in my module."

Answer (score 1):

Interchange below lines that should work !!

```
$max_length = 10; //variable_get('title_max_length');
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'myTHEME'). '/js/script.js');
drupal_add_js(array('common' => array('max' => $max_length)), array('type' => 'setting'));
```

to

```
$max_length = 10; //variable_get('title_max_length');
drupal_add_js(array('common' => array('max' => $max_length)), array('type' => 'setting'));
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'myTHEME'). '/js/script.js');
```

Comment: it shows `Drupal.settings.common is undefined` , and Drupal.settings.common.max; did not appear

Comment: I am trying to add this JS to a admin theme, maybe cuz admin theme is different from main one, and its not working

Comment: Yes, That might be the reason... Make sure you add to the same page where you are executing the Javascript to read it !

Comment: I just updated the answer !! may be order of loading java-script files is making an issue !!! And make sure above comment is taken care.. Give it a try !

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but it not helped) **BUT** i have fixed this issue, it was a wrong code in my module in `if else statement` sorry for this stupid thing, THANKS FOR HELP